# Hibernate/JPA: How to find sub entities using InheritanceType.JOINED

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

Can you, given a SuperEntity which is extended by three sub entities **SubEntityA**, **SubEntityB** and **SubEntityC**, perform a criteria query on SuperEntity to retrieve only instances of **SubEntityB** and **SubEntityC**?

With InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE you can set a discriminator value which I believe is used to query. How is it done with the InheritanceType.JOINED?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) You can include (redundant) `@DiscriminatorColumn`/`@DiscriminatorValue`s in a JOINED entity hierarchy too.

b) You can use the JPQL `type` operator: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#JPQL_special_operators , like `SELECT se FROM SuperEntity se WHERE TYPE(se) <> SubEntityA`

c) Use multiple queries (`SELECT se FROM SubEntityB se` + `SELECT se FROM SubEntityC se`) to collect all entities of interest.

Comment: On a) you mean an own String column? Or can it be done through @DiscriminatorValue(value= "MyClass")

Comment: @DiscriminatorColumn and @DiscriminatorValue will work for `SINGLE_TABLE` as well as for `JOINED`. If you want, you may even 'override' the discriminator column with a read-only field in your entity to be able to get clean JPQL queries.

Comment: Why do you say "redundant". If you don't define it, it doesn't get created to my knowledge. My tables lack one.

Comment: It's redundant because you don't have to have one; for `JOINED`, Hibernate will figure out the runtime type of an entity without using a discriminator, yet you *can* declare one and Hibernate will create a column and insert values, even though it does not itself make use of it. It's redundant because the information it contains can be deduced from looking at the other data in the joined tables, which is what Hibernate acutally does.

Comment: But how do I query it using criteria, get me only those instances. It doesn't sound redundant. There is no information in the database on what the type is.

Comment: That's right. If there's no discriminator, there is no *data field* that can be queried for the type. For pure JPQL you will then probably have to use the `TYPE` operator or explicitly query for specific entities `SELECT FROM SubEntityB` + `SELECT FROM SubEntityC`.